# How to solve this differential equation via undetermined coefficient method - Linear Independence Explanation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac {dy}{dt} = 3y + 6t^2 - e^{3t} - 2$$

I solved for the complementary solution which is $$ ke^{3t}$$ I guess the following trial solution

$$Ae^{3t} + Bt^2 + Ct + D $$

However, this has a term that is identical to the complementary solution. How can I go ahead and make this linearly independent? I know I need to multiply something with t but which term and why?

Comment: Since you already have $e^{3t}$ guess $A t e^{3t}+\cdots$

Comment: So only multiple the term that is common with the complementary solution and not the rest?

Comment: Correct ${}{}{}$